# Google Adwords Invalid Clicks

Tags: google-ads-api, fraud-prevention

guys, I've been struggling with a person who has attacked my Google AdWords account and he started to clicks on my websites with some proxies from all around the world, I have excluded all the countries except Iran and the point is I still getting IP addresses from every part of the world I have no idea how it possible but google count those clicks as a valid clicks and there is no invalid activity on my account.
I was wondering if anybody could show me a way at least I could stop this process.

Comment: don't block countries. you can exclude or block IP range.

Comment: it might be worth noting this as well: "if Google ads cannot be served in those countries, then there is no point getting fake leads from those countries with source of origin as Google AdWords."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly not a programming problem.